# Returning the complete value in recursions

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I've written a C++ code to convert a base 10 number into base two, but don't want the function to print it, but to return the value since I'll later need to use it in another function. The problem with returning is that the first time it returns it'll break out of the function, so it won't finish the process of converting and instead of returning '101' for '5', it will simply return '1' and that's it. Any ideas to fix this? I appreciate in advance.
Here's also my code:

```
int two;
int base(int a)
{

    if(a==1)
    {
        two=a%2;
    }
    else
    {
        base(a/2);
        two=a%2;
    }
    return two;
}
```

Note: Of course the code works pretty well if I change the return type into void and simply print the value. But I want to RETURN the value.

Comment: You should calculate remainders and store them in a vector. Now your function just return last number in 2nd base of a number

Comment: there's no need for a vector. she may maintain a factor of 10 which is multiplied by 10 on recursion return, and sum up remainders multiplied by factor

Comment: And don't declare your temporary variable outside the function itself...

Comment: @mangusta I find this solution the best! Thought of it already but was open to other new ideas as well... Turns out that this way is the simplest, thank you!

Comment: @mangusta sorry to disturb you again, I guess I'm still doing sth wrong: `void base(int a)
{
    int k=1;
    int mul=0;
    int two;
    if(a==1)
    {
        two=1;
    }
    else
    {
        base(a/2);
        two=a%2;
        mul += (k*two);
        k *= 10;
    }
    cout<< mul;
}`

Comment: @Liana see the posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of summing up (in fact it can be implemented iteratively but it seems you need to apply recursion so I provided recursive solution):

```
int baseHelper(int a, int factor) 
{
    int returnedValue = 0;

    if(a==0 || a==1)     
       returnedValue = factor * a;

    else     
    {        
        int addend = factor * (a%2);
        returnedValue =  addend + baseHelper(a/2, factor*10);  
    }     

    return returnedValue;
}

int base(int a)
{
    return baseHelper(a, 1);
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<=256; i++)
        cout << "i=" << i << " " << base(i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use recursion, you can return `std::string` like this:

```
std::string base(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return "0";
    else if (a == 1)
        return "1";
    else
        return base(a / 2) + ((a % 2) ? "1" : "0");
}
```

Using `std::to_chars` or `std::from_chars` from `<charconv>` is also an alternative.

Comment: from the caller's perspective, this is not a good solution. why should I care about converting the returned value into integer?